# GluonMobile application gives a black screen with PositionService

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to run an application that uses `PositionService` on an Android device (using Galaxy S7) and I'm getting a black scree. This is what `adb logcat *:W` showed, updated to add the suggestion in the comment:

```
03-15 19:20:42.430  6470  6470 E ProActivieLaunch: Sending Broadcast
03-15 19:20:42.433  1371  1371 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity:856 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$ActiveLaunchReceiver.onReceive:18092 android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52226:1319 android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0:4 android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run:0
03-15 19:20:42.435  1371  1371 E ActivityManager: TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
03-15 19:20:42.467 12294 12294 E Zygote  : isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
03-15 19:20:42.469 12294 12294 E libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
03-15 19:20:42.469 12294 12294 E libpersona: Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
03-15 19:20:42.474 12294 12294 W SELinux : SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G930V_8.0.0_0016, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
03-15 19:20:42.523   735   756 E ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
03-15 19:20:42.534  1371  1528 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
03-15 19:20:42.534  1371  1528 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl initialized
03-15 19:20:42.552  1371  1922 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to ProcessRecord{80c0b61 12101:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a25} (pid=12101, uid=10025) requires com.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.sec.android.app.launcher (uid 10080)
03-15 19:20:42.553  1371  1922 W BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$GmsExternalReceiver requires com.android.launcher.permission.RECEIVE_LAUNCH_BROADCASTS due to sender com.sec.android.app.launcher (uid 10080)
03-15 19:20:42.626  7285  7391 E HwDetectorWithState: a: 3
03-15 19:20:42.639  2667  2667 W SemDesktopModeManager: Desktop Mode feature not available or SemDesktopModeManager not instantiated. Please check Configuration.semDesktopModeEnabled instead.
03-15 19:20:42.654 12294 12294 W System.err: onCreate called, writing this to System.err
03-15 19:20:42.821 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: AndroidVM called JNI_OnLoad, vm = 0x7a938d0a80, androidEnv = 0x7a938d7300
03-15 19:20:42.822 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: nativeSetSurface called, env at 0x7a938d7300 and size 8, surface at 0x7fff8736c8
03-15 19:20:42.822 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: native setSurface Ready, native window at 0x7a803be010
03-15 19:20:42.823 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: SurfaceReady, surface at 0x7fff8736a8
03-15 19:20:42.823 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: SurfaceReady, native window at 0x7a803be010
03-15 19:20:42.826 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: nativeSetSurface called, env at 0x7a938d7300 and size 8, surface at 0x7fff8736d8
03-15 19:20:42.826 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: native setSurface Ready, native window at 0x7a803be010
03-15 19:20:42.826 12294 12315 E GraalGluon: Start GraalApp, DALVIK env at 0x7a802f6d00
03-15 19:20:42.826 12294 12315 E GraalGluon: PAGESIZE = 4096
03-15 19:20:42.827 12294 12315 E GraalGluon: EnvVersion = 65542
03-15 19:20:42.827 12294 12315 E GraalGluon: calling JavaMainWrapper_run with argsize: 22
03-15 19:20:42.829 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: launcher, nativeSurfaceRedrawNeeded called. Invoke method on glass_monocle
03-15 19:20:42.840 12294 12317 E javafx  : In JNI_OnLoad_prism_es2
03-15 19:20:42.856 12294 12318 E GraalGluon: In dummy JNI_OnLoad_javafx_font
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7a72922380
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "Thread-6" daemon prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12c80000 self=0x7a72a1b200
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=12318 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7a6d0ff4f0
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 167579477 1591564 26 ) utm=16 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7a6d005000-0x7a6d007000 stackSize=1005KB
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 00000000003973ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dba0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002d57b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002d5d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+176)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 0000000000462688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+544)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 0000000000107be4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+116)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 0000000000106840  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+856)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000000000010a468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI19GetMethodIDInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassS2_S2_b+648)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 00000000016296a4  /data/app/com.gps.demo-MkRu6Hmm_2v8gjcRCIaS1w==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (initializeDalvikHandles+316)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   (no managed stack frames)
03-15 19:20:43.044 12294 12318 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]
03-15 19:20:43.329 12294 12294 E GraalGluon: launcher, nativeSurfaceRedrawNeeded called. Invoke method on glass_monocle
03-15 19:20:43.401  1371  1996 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: com_qualcomm_qtiperformance_native_perf_io_prefetch_start
03-15 19:20:43.401  1371  1996 E ANDR-PERF-JNI: gIOPHAl initialized
03-15 19:20:43.403   735   756 E ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
```

The app is simple:

```
public class GPSApplication extends Application {

    private final AppManager appManager = AppManager.initialize(this::postInit);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        appManager.addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, HomeView::new);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        appManager.start(stage);
    }

    private void postInit(Scene scene) {}

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty(com.gluonhq.attach.util.Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG, "true");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
public class HomeView extends View {

    private PositionService positionService;

    public HomeView() {
        positioning();
    }

    private void positioning() {
        PositionService.create().ifPresent(service -> {
            positionService = service;
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Removing the `positioning` method makes the application load properly.

The pom was mainly copied from Gluon, and I added the positioning service from attach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.gps.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gpsdemo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>GPSDemo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>17.0.1</javafx.version>
        <charm.version>6.1.0</charm.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.13</attach.version>
        <connect.version>2.0.1</connect.version>
        <javafx.maven.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.maven.plugin.version>
        <gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>1.0.12</gluonfx.maven.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.10.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <main.class>com.gpsdemo.GPSApplication</main.class>
        <app.identifier>${main.class}</app.identifier>
        <app.description>The GPSDemo app</app.description>
        <package.type/>
        <mac.app.store/>
        <mac.signing.user.name/>
        <bundle.version/>
        <bundle.short.version/>
        <version.code/>
        <provided.keystore.path/>
        <provided.keystore.password/>
        <provided.key.alias/>
        <provided.key.alias.password/>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>${charm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect</artifactId>
            <version>${connect.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>position</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                        <list>position</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                    <appIdentifier>${app.identifier}</appIdentifier>
                    <releaseConfiguration>
                        <vendor>Gluon</vendor>
                        <description>${app.description}</description>
                        <packageType>${package.type}</packageType>
                        <!-- for macOS/iOS -->
                        <macAppStore>${mac.app.store}</macAppStore>
                        <bundleShortVersion>${bundle.short.version}</bundleShortVersion>
                        <bundleVersion>${bundle.version}</bundleVersion>
                        <!-- for Android -->
                        <versionCode>${version.code}</versionCode>
                        <providedKeyStorePath>${provided.keystore.path}</providedKeyStorePath>
                        <providedKeyStorePassword>${provided.keystore.password}</providedKeyStorePassword>
                        <providedKeyAlias>${provided.key.alias}</providedKeyAlias>
                        <providedKeyAliasPassword>${provided.key.alias.password}</providedKeyAliasPassword>
                    </releaseConfiguration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>desktop</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>host</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <properties>
                <package.type>pkg</package.type>
                <mac.app.store>false</mac.app.store>
                <bundle.version>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.0</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macstore</id>
            <properties>
                <package.type>pkg</package.type>
                <mac.app.store>true</mac.app.store>
                <bundle.version>1.${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.6</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
                <bundle.version>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</bundle.version>
                <bundle.short.version>1.0</bundle.short.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
                <app.identifier>com.gps.demo</app.identifier>
                <version.code>${env.GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}</version.code>
                <provided.keystore.path>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTOREPATH}</provided.keystore.path>
                <provided.keystore.password>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}</provided.keystore.password>
                <provided.key.alias>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS}</provided.key.alias>
                <provided.key.alias.password>${env.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS_PASSWORD}</provided.key.alias.password>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>pi</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>linux-aarch64</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The apk was generated using github actions, again, copied mostly from Gluon's examples. I removed the part about publishing to Google Play as I only want an apk generated as an artifact.

```
name: Android

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Gluon's GraalVM
        uses: gluonhq/setup-graalvm@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Install libraries
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt install libasound2-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libgl-dev libgtk-3-dev libpango1.0-dev libxtst-dev

      - name: Gluon Build
        run: mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:build gluonfx:package
        env:
          GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTOREPATH: ${{ steps.android_keystore_file.outputs.filePath }}
          GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD }}
          GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS: ${{ secrets.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS }}
          GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.GLUON_ANDROID_KEYALIAS_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: Android package
          path: target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/GPSDemo.apk
```

I also tried installing the apk on an Android Studio emulator on Windows 10 and got an `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error on installation. I assumed it's because I'm on Windows, but would like to know if I can install and run the application on an emulator to compare with the physical device and see if I get the same error.

Comment: Can you add `System.setProperty(com.gluonhq.attach.util.Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG,"true");` to your main method and try again on your Android device? That should give you a more verbose output. Also, have you tried [HelloMaps](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloMaps) sample?

Comment: @JoséPereda I added the line and rerun , the log is updated now. I still filtered to show only warnings+, should I reduce the level? I will try the maps sample.

Comment: You can run `adb logcat -v threadtime`, that shows all logs. Usually for the JNI crashes it contains additional valuable information.

Comment: @JoséPereda The log is too lengthy to post on SO since it's not filtered, I put it here: https://pastebin.com/i4dxheYQ. Is there a way to filter only for the relevant parts (like the launching of the app)?

Comment: My impression is that you are calling the positionService too early. Can you try doing it at some later state (i.e when the view is shown, or calling it from a button action?). Typically `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:nativerun` only shows logs for the app.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'm building the new app which will activate the service with a button press, will report soon about it. I'm building with Github Actions, so I don't think I can use the maven command.

Comment: Okay, in that case, see the [command line](https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/substrate/target/AndroidTargetConfiguration.java#L211)  that it's actually invoked.

Comment: @JoséPereda Those debug args really help, thanks. The application launches fine now: https://pastebin.com/Sj8Aib3F. However, now when I start the service and call `getPosition` the application hangs. I will create a new question for this since it's at least launching now. You can post an answer to this one. I highly recommend that the initialization order be documented. I can file a bug for this service, but there could be other services that are also affected.

Comment: I posted the next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71490922/gluonmobile-application-hangs-when-reading-position-from-positionservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/issues/296) in the Attach service. It was [fixed](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/pull/297) and works with version 4.0.14.