# GluonMobile application hangs when reading position from PositionService

Tags: java, android, gluon-mobile

This is a continuation to [GluonMobile application gives a black screen with PositionService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477853/gluonmobile-application-gives-a-black-screen-with-positionservice). Using the same files from there, with the following new change:

```
public class HomeView extends View {

    private PositionService positionService;
    private Button posButton = new Button("Activate position");

    public HomeView() {
        posButton.setOnAction(e -> positioning());
        setCenter(posButton);
    }

    private void positioning() {
        PositionService.create().ifPresent(service -> {
            positionService = service;
            System.out.println("service created: " + positionService);
            positionService.start();
            System.out.println("service started: " + positionService);
            positionService.stop();
            System.out.println("service stopped: " + positionService);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Run and press the button. The application hangs with the button in the pressed state. Running `adb logcat -v color`, this is what happens when the button is pressed:

```
03-16 23:19:23.738  1371  2407 D InputReader: Input event(6): value=1 when=4704804257163000
03-16 23:19:23.739  1371  2407 D InputReader: Input event(6): value=1 when=4704804257163000
03-16 23:19:23.739  1371  2407 I InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=0.13197 ] when=4704804257163000
03-16 23:19:23.740  1371  2406 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (2667): action: 0x4, toolType: 1
03-16 23:19:23.740  1371  2406 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (21531): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
03-16 23:19:23.743 21531 21531 D ViewRootImpl@233d1ae[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
03-16 23:19:23.745 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.745 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.745 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.745 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.745   724   724 D SEC LightsHAL: button : 1 +
03-16 23:19:23.746 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.746 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]]
03-16 23:19:23.746 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]]
03-16 23:19:23.747 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=218,y=297,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[212]]
03-16 23:19:23.763 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.763 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.763 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.764 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.764 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.764 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]]
03-16 23:19:23.766 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=297]]
03-16 23:19:23.770   724   724 D SEC LightsHAL: button : 1 -
03-16 23:19:23.782 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.782 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.782 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.783 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.783 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.783 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.783 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.783 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=218,y=296,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[212]]
03-16 23:19:23.799 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.799 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.799 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.799 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.803 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.803 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.803 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=218,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.833 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.833 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.833 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.833 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.835 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.835 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.835 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.835 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=217,y=296,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[212]]
03-16 23:19:23.849 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.850 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.850 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.850 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.850  1371  2407 D InputReader: Input event(6): value=0 when=4704804369677000
03-16 23:19:23.850  1371  2407 D InputReader: Input event(6): value=0 when=4704804369677000
03-16 23:19:23.850  1371  2407 I InputReader: Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=4704804369677000
03-16 23:19:23.851  1371  2406 I InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (21531): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
03-16 23:19:23.852 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.853 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.853 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.855 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.856 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.856 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.856 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.857 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.857 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.858 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[1,TouchState.Point[id=0,x=217,y=296]]
03-16 23:19:23.858 21531 21531 D ViewRootImpl@233d1ae[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
03-16 23:19:23.860 21531 21531 V GraalActivity: Activity, get touch event, pcount = 1
03-16 23:19:23.860 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, pass to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.860 21531 21531 I GLASS   : Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
03-16 23:19:23.860 21531 21531 E GraalGluon: Native Dalvik layer got touch event, passed to native Graal layer...
03-16 23:19:23.861 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: don't add points, primary = -1
03-16 23:19:23.861 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Pushing TouchState[0] to TouchPipeline[SmallMove]
03-16 23:19:23.861 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Applying SmallMove to TouchState[0]
03-16 23:19:23.861 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set TouchState[0]
03-16 23:19:23.861 21531 21550 D GraalCompiled: traceEvent: Set MouseState[x=217,y=296,wheel=0,buttonsPressed=IntSet[]]
03-16 23:19:23.862 21531 21554 D GluonAttach: Initializing native position from OnLoad
03-16 23:19:23.862 21531 21554 D GraalGluon: ATTACH_DALVIK, tid = 21554, existed? 1, dalvikEnv at 0x7a803ed600
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7a72b29380
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "Thread-6" daemon prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x17f00000 self=0x7a8034e400
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=21554 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7a6d1ff4f0
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 411261097 9035260 151 ) utm=28 stm=13 core=1 HZ=100
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7a6d105000-0x7a6d107000 stackSize=1005KB
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 00000000003973ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dba0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002d57b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002d5d28  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+176)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 0000000000462688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+544)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 0000000000107be4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck13CheckInstanceERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessENS0_12InstanceKindEP8_jobjectb+116)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 0000000000106840  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+856)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 000000000010a468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI19GetMethodIDInternalEPKcP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassS2_S2_b+648)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 0000000001629be4  /data/app/com.gps.demo-0NdG_lWfGchX6RZBHXarHg==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (initializeDalvikHandles+316)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   (no managed stack frames)
03-16 23:19:23.890 21531 21554 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete log? It doesn't show anything that reflects it is hanging? Also use `Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG`, and even add some printouts to the `positioning()` call.

Comment: @JoséPereda I ran a less restrictive logging command. There is something about JNI failing. I also added prints, but I don't see them in the log. `Constants.ATTACH_DEBUG` is set to `true` from the previous question already.

Comment: You are getting the crash inside this JNI [method](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/position/src/main/native/android/c/position.c#L45), but I can't say why. Can you verify that you call the service from the JavaFX Application Thread (Use `Platform.runLater`). Btw, did you test HelloMaps? That should work for you out of the box. If it does, see what's different from your app.

Comment: @JoséPereda I tried with `Platform.runLater`, didn't change anything. I tested HelloMaps and it also gives a black screen on launch. I had to copy it into a separate project so I can build it on GitHub - https://github.com/nlisker/hello-maps2, also contains the created apk artifact under Actions ("Initial Commit" run) if you want to try yourself. I posted the full log here: https://pastebin.com/PVGUEmGL (line 292 is the JNI error). The service is loaded before the view is, so it's the same issue in my previous question with the black screen.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to reproduce the issue, and even isolate the problem. Filed an [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/issues/296), and [fixed](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/pull/297) it.

Comment: @JoséPereda Excellent! Are other services also affected? I might be needing the accelerometer too. When there's a deployed (test or stable) version of Attach with this fix I volunteer to test it. Until then, is 4.12 unaffected?

Comment: Last release without this bug was 4.0.11, but you can already use the 4.0.14-SNAPSHOT (adding `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots` to the list of repositories of your pom).

Comment: @JoséPereda I tested the snapshot with both Position and Accelerometer services and they load fine. Thanks. You can post an answer to one of these questions or closer one as a duplicate. Now I'm hitting https://github.com/gluonhq/substrate/issues/1114, but it's not as bad.