# Gluon Attach 4.0.16 causes black screen on startup

Tags: java, gluon-mobile

Using:

```
<maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.10.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
<maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
<javafx-maven-plugin-version>0.0.8</javafx-maven-plugin-version>
<gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>1.0.15</gluonfx-maven-plugin-version>

<java-version>17</java-version>
<javafx-version>19</javafx-version>
<charm-version>6.1.0</charm-version>
<attach-version>4.0.16</attach-version>
```

Specifying `javafxStaticSdkVersion` as 19 and using graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final.

With the following services and matching dependencies:

```
<attachList>
    <list>display</list>
    <list>lifecycle</list>
    <list>statusbar</list>
    <list>storage</list>
    <list>position</list>
    <list>accelerometer</list>
    <list>magnetometer</list>
    <list>audio</list>
</attachList>
```

When launching an app, a black screen is shown. With Attach version 4.0.15 the app works fine. A similar issue, [GluonMobile application gives a black screen with PositionService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477853/gluonmobile-application-gives-a-black-screen-with-positionservice), was present in 4.0.14, so maybe a regression.

adb logcat shows no exceptions.

**Edit:** Updated to `GluonFX 1.0.16-SNAPSHOT`, and removed the filtering in adb logcat, now it shows an exception:

```
10-17 15:04:24.966 26884 26908 D GluonAttach: Util :: Load className com/gluonhq/helloandroid/DalvikDisplayService
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.os.Handler.<init>(android.os.Handler$Callback, boolean) (Handler.java:203)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.os.Handler.<init>() (Handler.java:117)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.content.ClipboardManager$2.<init>(android.content.ClipboardManager) (ClipboardManager.java:84)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void android.content.ClipboardManager.<init>(android.content.Context, android.os.Handler) (ClipboardManager.java:84)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.content.ClipboardManager android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$12.createService(android.app.ContextImpl) (SystemServiceRegistry.java:379)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$12.createService(android.app.ContextImpl) (SystemServiceRegistry.java:377)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.app.SystemServiceRegistry$CachedServiceFetcher.getService(android.app.ContextImpl) (SystemServiceRegistry.java:1402)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.app.SystemServiceRegistry.getSystemService(android.app.ContextImpl, java.lang.String) (SystemServiceRegistry.java:1354)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(java.lang.String) (ContextImpl.java:1695)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(java.lang.String) (ContextThemeWrapper.java:171)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String) (Activity.java:6008)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at void com.gluonhq.helloandroid.Util.<init>(android.app.Activity) (Util.java:53)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to NewStringUTF
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504] "Thread-6" daemon prio=5 tid=16 Runnable
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12e80000 self=0x7e74f27800
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=26908 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7e604ff4f0
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 106877037 2373803 92 ) utm=9 stm=1 core=2 HZ=100
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x7e60405000-0x7e60407000 stackSize=1005KB
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 00000000003973ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dba0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #02 pc 00000000002d57b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1040)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #03 pc 00000000002d5c38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_St9__va_list+116)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #04 pc 0000000000108878  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+148)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #05 pc 00000000001083a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck11CheckThreadEP7_JNIEnv+536)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #06 pc 0000000000106840  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+856)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #07 pc 00000000000fd004  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI12NewStringUTFEP7_JNIEnvPKc+648)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #08 pc 00000000019c07f0  /data/app/com.gps.demo-vSN-YTEtwQ1kgcyL1xFIMg==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (registerDalvikClass+448)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #09 pc 00000000019be2e4  /data/app/com.gps.demo-vSN-YTEtwQ1kgcyL1xFIMg==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (initializeDisplayDalvikHandles+36)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #10 pc 00000000019bde90  /data/app/com.gps.demo-vSN-YTEtwQ1kgcyL1xFIMg==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (JNI_OnLoad_display+140)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #11 pc 00000000002e2ea8  /data/app/com.gps.demo-vSN-YTEtwQ1kgcyL1xFIMg==/lib/arm64/libsubstrate.so (JNILibraryInitializer_callOnLoadFunction_7833a452cbe2b969eec248ff45fd5fe129f3cbdc+104)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   (no managed stack frames)
10-17 15:04:24.982 26884 26908 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]
```

Comment: Can you test with GluonFX 1.0.16-SNAPSHOT? (Add `<pluginRepository>` with this URL to your pom: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)

Comment: @JoséPereda I'll try. Can you also look at my previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73817103/missing-toggle-button-in-settings-pane

Comment: @JoséPereda Still black screen with GluonFX 1.0.16-SNAPSHOT. Is it not a problem in Attach considering that bumping that version causes the issue?

Comment: There were some changes for Android 31 in both Substrate (GluonFX plugin) and Attach, that is why I was asking. Can you run `adb logcat` (instead of `mvn -Pandroid gluonfx:nativerun` which trims down the output messages) and see if you find any exception?

Comment: @JoséPereda There is an exception now. I posted it in the question. There is a lot more output, so if you are looking for something specific I will search for it.

Comment: Ok, that helps somehow. Can you file an issue [here](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/issues) and post at least the pom and device and Android version? Does it happen in other devices?

Comment: @JoséPereda Filed #341. I don't have another device to test on right now. I will try to get a colleague to test as well, he uses Android 12 I think.

Comment: Thanks. If you can share it, or maybe just part or it, feel free to upload an apk to the issue.

Comment: @JoséPereda I linked a minimal APK. I can share the code too, but there's really nothing there more than the basic application class with a single view.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested on my Pixel XL (Android 10.0) and it works fine, no black screen.